# Make IIS web.config Read PHP Environment Variable

Tags: php, iis

I have a problem where I get 404s for a couple seconds after clearing the cache of WP Rocket on IIS (where I have a rule that directs the user directly to the .html cached file).

To address the problem, I want to add a rule to my web.config that disables the direct-to-html-cache rule whenever WP Rocket is doing something.

I have already hooked into the plugin and am setting a PHP environment variable equal to true or false based on whether the caching plugin is busy.

How can I use this environment variable inside of a web.config?

Here's my web.config in case any of you are trying to serve WP Rocket files w/o any PHP on IIS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="Vary" />
        <add name="Vary" value="Accept-Encoding" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <!--<serverRuntime enabled="true" frequentHitThreshold="1" frequentHitTimePeriod="00:30:00" />-->
    <!--<caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
      <profiles>
        <add extension=".html" duration="3:00:00" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
      </profiles>
    </caching>-->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear/>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"
          />
        </rule>
        <rule name="WP Rocket" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".*=.*" negate="true" />
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".*attachment_id=.*" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" pattern="^.*(comment_author_|wordpress|wp-postpass_).*$" negate="true" />
            <!--<add input="{WP_ROCKET_BUSY}" pattern="true" negate="true">-->
            <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}index-https.html" matchType="IsFile"
            />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}index-https.html" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Check backup folder if CSS/JS does not exist in primary directory" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="wp-content\/cache\/min\/1\/(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/min/1/{R:1}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/min/backup/{R:1}" matchType="IsFile" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wp-content/cache/min/backup/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Wordpress Pretty Permalinks" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <!--<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />-->
    <!--<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />-->
    <!-- Microsoft sets runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to true by default
             You should handle this according to need, but consider the performance hit.
             Good source of reference on this matter: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Oct/25/Caveats-with-the-runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests-in-IIS-78
        -->
    <!--<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />-->
    <!--<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />-->
    <staticContent>
      <!-- Remove ETAG IN IIS >8 ; for IIS 7/7.5 see the Rewrite rules (bigger description of why you might remove etag down there aswell)
            <clientCache setEtag="false"/>
            -->
      <!-- Set expire headers to 30 days for static content-->
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
      <remove fileExtension=".html" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <remove fileExtension=".css" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css" />
      <remove fileExtension=".js" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".rss" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".rss" mimeType="application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
      <remove fileExtension=".xml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="application/xml; charset=UTF-8" />
      <remove fileExtension=".mp3" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp3" mimeType="audio/mpeg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ogg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="audio/ogg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ogv" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".webm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <remove fileExtension=".svgz" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ttc" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttc" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/opentype" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
      <remove fileExtension=".crx" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".crx" mimeType="application/x-chrome-extension" />
      <remove fileExtension=".xpi" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".xpi" mimeType="application/x-xpinstall" />
      <remove fileExtension=".safariextz" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".safariextz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <remove fileExtension=".flv" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".flv" mimeType="video/x-flv" />
      <remove fileExtension=".f4v" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".f4v" mimeType="video/mp4" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ico" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ico" mimeType="image/x-icon" />
      <remove fileExtension=".webp" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
      <remove fileExtension=".htc" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".htc" mimeType="text/x-component" />
      <remove fileExtension=".vcf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".vcf" mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
      <remove fileExtension=".torrent" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".torrent" mimeType="application/x-bittorrent" />
      <remove fileExtension=".cur" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".cur" mimeType="image/x-icon" />
      <remove fileExtension=".webapp" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webapp" mimeType="application/x-web-app-manifest+json; charset=UTF-8" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```